# filesize conversion bytes to kb/mb/gb function does not work as expected

Tags: php, file, switch-statement, filesize, php-5.5

I have this function:

```
function formatSizeUnits($bytes,array $options = array()){
        $forceFormat = isset($options["forceFormat"]) ? $options["forceFormat"] : false;
        $suffix = !isset($options["suffix"]) || $options["suffix"] === true ? true : false;
        switch($bytes):
            case $forceFormat === "gb":
            case $bytes >= 1073741824 && $forceFormat === false:
                $bytes = number_format($bytes / 1073741824, 2) . ($suffix === true ? " GB" : "");
                break;
            case $forceFormat === "mb":
            case $bytes >= 1048576 && $forceFormat === false:
                $bytes = number_format($bytes / 1048576, 2) . ($suffix === true ? " MB" : "");
                break;
            case $forceFormat === "kb":
            case $bytes >= 1024 && $forceFormat === false:
                $bytes = number_format($bytes / 1024, 2) . ($suffix === true ? " KB" : "");
                break;
            case $forceFormat === "b":
            case $bytes > 1 && $forceFormat === false:
                $bytes = $bytes . ($suffix === true ? " bytes" : "");
                break;
            case $bytes == 1 && $forceFormat === false:
                $bytes = $bytes . ($suffix === true ? " byte" : "");
                break;
            default:
                $bytes = "0".($suffix === true ? " bytes" : "");
        endswitch;
    return $bytes;
    }
```

When I run it like this:

```
formatSizeUnits(0);
```

It returns this:
`0.00 GB`

`$forceFormat` is `false` and `$suffix` is `true` in that case.

I don't understand why it is returning in `GB`. I want it to return just `0 bytes`.

When I put a `var_dump` in the first switch statement (the one of `gb`) it says this:

```
case $forceFormat === "gb":
            case $bytes >= 1073741824 && $forceFormat === false:
                var_dump($bytes >= 1073741824, $forceFormat);
```

Result:

```
(bool(false)
bool(false)
```

I'm wondering why both `$bytes >= 1073741824` and `$forceFormat` can be false and it still runs that case.
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `$bytes` is `0` the expression `$bytes >= 1073741824 && $forceFormat === false` evaluates to `false`. The `switch` statement jumps to the first `case` whose expression matches `$bytes`. The following script demonstrates, that `false` matches `0`.

```
<?php       
switch (0) {
  case false:
    echo '0 is false';
    break;
  case true:
    echo '0 is true';
    break;
  default:
    echo '0 is something else';
    break;
}
?>
```

Because you want to jump to the first `case` which is `true` you should use `switch (true)`.

Comment: Ah I see. Yes.. That, unfortunately, sounds indedd very logical. Didn't think of that. Is there any way to avoid this and treat 0 as a number?

Comment: As I've mentioned above you just need to change `switch ($bytes)` to `switch (true)` for your code to work.

Comment: Ah, now I understand. So actually a switch statement is quite useless then.